# aggregate on nested type properties - using NEST

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I'm trying to aggregate on counts of nested type, or sum of property of nested types, but unable to get NEST to include more than one nested document in the calculation.

```
        var result = elasticClient.Search<ItemIncidents>(s => s
             .Aggregations(a => a
             .Terms("group by role", ts => ts
                 .Field(o => o.LabelName)
                 .d
                 .Aggregations(aa => aa
                     .Sum("sum incidents", sa => sa                           
                          .Field("incidents.index")))
                 )
             )
        );
```

The classes used are this:

```
public class ItemIncidents
{
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public string LabelName { get; set; }

  //  [ElasticProperty(Type = FieldType.Nested)]
    public List<IncidentInstance> Incidents { get; set; }
}

 public partial class IncidentInstance:     {
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public int Index { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
  }
```

If I have more than one incidentinstance per ItemIncident, elastic is only counting the last one in the list in the aggregate count of index.  If the value of Index = 3 for all the IncidentInstances, and there are five documents each with two incidentinstances, the result I'm getting is 15 (5*1*3), instead of 30 (5*2*3).

Is this an issue where I need to do some special attribute mapping on the Index field?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [nested aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-nested-aggregation.html) for nested type.

So, for your documents:

```
public class ItemIncidents
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string LabelName { get; set; }

    [ElasticProperty(Type = FieldType.Nested)]
    public List<IncidentInstance> Incidents { get; set; }
}

public class IncidentInstance
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public int Index { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

use aggregation

```
var searchResponse = client.Search<ItemIncidents>(s => s.Aggregations(a => a
    .Nested("indexCount", nested => nested
        .Path(p => p.Incidents)
        .Aggregations(aa => aa.Sum("sum", sum => sum.Field(f => f.Incidents.First().Index))))));
```